# rEFInd not showing additional Fedora entries

Tags: linux, fedora, refind

I have a machine that has Windowd 10, Fedora 38, and Fedora 39 installed. When I installed rEFInd, (and then ran `mkrlconf` on both Fedora installations) it was able to successfully pick up the Windows 10 and Fedora 38. However, it does not show anything for Fedora 39. I have verified that there is a `refind_linux.conf` file in my `/boot` directory of my Fedora 39 installation. Ironically enough, rEFInd is able to find the Grub bootloader that boots into Fedora 39, but I would really like it to find 39 directly.

Is there any way I can turn on some debug logging to the screen to show rEFInd's scanning process to see what is going on?